# What's the time interval of the git auto fetch option in VS Code, and is there a way to change it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, fetch

I want to decrease this time interval.

Comment: How often do you want to fetch and why?  if you want to update any time there's a change,  instead of fetching frequently you might set up a webhook using smee.io to notify your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git.autofetchPeriod` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo-file:

> ```json
> // Duration in seconds between each automatic git fetch, when `git.autofetch` is enabled.
> "git.autofetchPeriod": 180,
> ```